# xcode folders auto expanding so a particular state everytime

Tags: xcode

I am seeing my file manager constantly auto expand folders to a particular state.  I am not using a workspace or cocoapods in my app, although I had in the past.

Not sure how to reset the behavior so that it remembers the state I have selected and not that same state from the past.

I have seen threads advising to delete:

MyProjectName.xcodeproj > project.xcworkspace > xcuserdata > myusername.xcuserdatad > UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate

but I am not using a workspace so that is not applicable to me.

I am using source control and worried there may be some file from a previous workspace that is not being removed.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with a certain folder auto-expanding every time I opened the project. You can reset the workspace to solve it (although be aware this will remove any customization to the workspace too).

Just rename / delete:

```
[YourProjectName].xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace
[YourProjectName].xcodeproj/xcuserdata
```

See also here: [Xcode keeps expanding all groups in the project navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40283947/xcode-keeps-expanding-all-groups-in-the-project-navigator)